# Gente se me repite el messagebox y no se donde esta el error

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Se repite el código dos veces cuando se hace el **evento_leave**

```
string sql = "select * from Mineria where ExpedienteJudicial='" + textBox1.Text + "'";
string sql1 = "select * from Buscar where  ExpedienteJudicial='" + textBox1.Text + "'";
DataTable dt = Funciones.LeerBase(sql);
DataTable dt1 = Funciones.LeerBase(sql1);
if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
{

    MessageBox.Show("Ya existe un registro previo en la base de datos local.");
    txtAdtvo.Text = dt.Rows[0]["ExpedienteAdmin"].ToString();
    txtConcesionario.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Concesionario"].ToString();
    txtEmpresa.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Empresa"].ToString();
    txtDepartamento.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Departamento"].ToString();
   
    txtCaja.Focus();
    return;
   
}

else if(dt.Rows.Count == 0)
{

    MessageBox.Show("No existe registros previos en la base de datos local.");

                
               
                if (dt1.Rows.Count != 0)
                {

                    
                    txtAdtvo.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["ExpedienteAdmin"].ToString();
                    txtConcesionario.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["Concesionario"].ToString();
                    txtEmpresa.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["Empresa"].ToString();
                    txtDepartamento.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["Departamento"].ToString();
                    MessageBox.Show("Pero ya existe un registro previo en la base de datos del cliente.");
                    txtCaja.Focus();
                }
                else if (dt1.Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No existe registros previos en la base de datos del cliente.");
                    txtCaja.Focus();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Esto esta dentro de un evento leave en donde? a que apunta ese evento? si se ejecuta dos veces es porque hay 2 veces el evento...

Comment: es que esta arriba le hago el leave a un text box lo que quiero yo es que se ejectute una vez el message box pero si la condicion se cumple o no

Comment: y si lo hago por fuera del bucle me tira un error por que hay un else abajo

Comment: de que bucle hablas??? aca no se ve ningun bucle...

Comment: el mensaje que se repite es "No existe registros previos en la base de datos local" ?